# Google Sheet - OnEdit TimeStamp on separate Sheets not working

Tags: google-sheets

I was running Google Sheets with only 1 Sheet and this script (updating timestamp onEdit)

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (!e.value) return;
    e.source.getActivesheet()
        .getRange('G50')
        .setValue(new Date());
}
```

but as soon as I added 2 additional sheets, it stopped working. I dont get it, because I thought, this script will now run on either of these sheets as soon as I edit on. (but it does nothing)

What am I not thinking about? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a change as follows?

From :

```
e.source.getActivesheet()
```

To :

```
e.source.getActiveSheet()
```

In the case of onEdit(), even when an error occurs, the error doesn't display. So if you want to know whether the error occurs, please confirm "View > Execution Transcript" on Script Editor after onEdit() was launched. You can see the running process of onEdit() in the Execution Transcript.

Comment: thanks so much! I didn't think about the key-sensitivity. It's working now!